# Expose Action<T> as Action<object>

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, delegates

I'm creating a framework that contains a wrapper around a library (specifically [SharpBrake](https://github.com/asbjornu/SharpBrake)) that performs all interaction with SharpBrake via reflection so there's no hard dependency on the library to 3rd parties of my framework.

If 3rd parties of my framework wants to use SharpBrake, they can just stuff the SharpBrake.dll into the bin folder, but if they don't, they can just forget about it. If my framework had explicit references to SharpBrake types, users of my framework would get exceptions during runtime of SharpBrake.dll missing, which I don't want.

So, my wrapper first loads SharpBrake.dll from disk, finds the `AirbrakeClient` type, and stores a delegate pointing to the `AirbrakeClient.Send(AirbrakeNotice)` method in a private field. My problem, however, is that since the `Send()` method takes an `AirbrakeNotice` object and I can't reference the `AirbrakeNotice` object directly, I need to somehow convert the `Send()` method to an `Action<object>`.

I have a strong feeling this isn't possible, but I want to explore all options before settling on exposing `Delegate` and using `DynamicInvoke()`, which I assume is far from optimal, performance-wise. What I would love to do is the following:

```
Type clientType = exportedTypes.FirstOrDefault(type => type.Name == "AirbrakeClient");
Type noticeType = exportedTypes.FirstOrDefault(type => type.Name == "AirbrakeNotice");
MethodInfo sendMethod = clientType.GetMethod("Send", new[] { noticeType });
object client = Activator.CreateInstance(clientType);
Type actionType = Expression.GetActionType(noticeType);
Delegate sendMethodDelegate = Delegate.CreateDelegate(actionType, client, sendMethod);

// This fails with an InvalidCastException:
Action<object> sendAction = (Action<object>)sendMethodDelegate;
```

However, this fails with the following exception:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Action`1[SharpBrake.Serialization.AirbrakeNotice]' to type 'System.Action`1[System.Object]'.

Obviously, because `sendMethodDelegate` is an `Action<AirbrakeNotice>` and not an `Action<object>`. Since I can't mention `AirbrakeNotice` in my code, I'm forced to do this:

```
Action<object> sendAction = x => sendMethodDelegate.DynamicInvoke(x);
```

or just exposing the `Delegate sendMethodDelegate` directly. Is this possible? I know that there's chance of getting into situations where the `object` can be of a different type than `AirbrakeNotice` which would be bad, but seeing how much you can mess up with reflection anyway, I'm hoping there's a loophole somewhere.

Comment: I'd avoid extended use of reflections if you are concerned about performance.  If you can come up with an `interface` for the class(es) you are using, then I'd create one.  Then write a wrapper that implements the interface by calling into the SharpBreak code, and stuff it in a separate DLL.  Then dynamically load just your wrapper assembly and concrete wrapper type(s), and call into that interface.  Then you don't have to do reflections at a method level.

Comment: @Merlyn I wish I could upvote you more than once.

Comment: After having a quick look at their code, this might be as simple as wrapping `SharpBrake.Extensions`, which has a whopping two methods.  Do you have to call more than those extension methods in your app?

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham, please post an answer with a code example. I don't quite understand how using interfaces can achieve the loose coupling I want.

Comment: @asbjornu: You still have to use reflections, but only on types.  I've added an answer with a code sample.  It is hard to tell exactly what you need in *your* app from that library.  The library's docs just say to call a single extension method, and you seem to be trying to wrap all of the library.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham, in addition to the types I've included in my example, I also wrap `AirbrakeNoticeBuilder.BuildNotice()` to create the `AirbrakeNotice` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need below C# 4 support you can get much greater performance using the `dynamic` vs `DynamicInvoke`.

```
Action<dynamic> sendAction = x => sendMethodDelegate(x);
```

Actually I guess you wouldn't even need the above if you can use dynamic, because it would increase performance and simplify everything if you just did:

```
Type clientType = exportedTypes.FirstOrDefault(type => type.Name == "AirbrakeClient");
dynamic client = Activator.CreateInstance(clientType);

...
client.Send(anAirbrakeNotice);
```

But if you need to support .net 3.5 jon skeets answer with expression trees is definitely the way to go.

Comment: This is a great idea for .NET 4.0. I hadn't thought about the possibility, but it might actually make sense to require .NET 4 for this. I'll let it brew for some time, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 6):

If you're happy to use expression trees, it's reasonably simple:

```
ConstantExpression target = Expression.Constant(client, clientType);

ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "x");
Expression converted = Expression.Convert(parameter, noticeType);
Expression call = Expression.Call(target, sendMethod, converted);

Action<object> action = Expression.Lambda<Action<object>>(call, parameter)
                                  .Compile();
```

I *think* that's what you want...

Comment: That's indeed what I'm asking for. Thanks for the great answer! However, reading some of the other suggestions here, I might be asking for the wrong thing, so I'm going to test the different solutions provided before accepting any answer.

Comment: Often doing heavy reflection implementations myself, I wrote [a helper class which does this](https://github.com/Whathecode/Framework-Class-Library-Extension/blob/master/Whathecode.System/DelegateHelper.cs). E.g. `DelegateHelper.CreateDelegate<Action<object>>( sendMethod, target, CreateOptions.Downcasting )`. Some information about it [can be found here](http://whathecode.wordpress.com/2011/05/25/creating-delegates-during-reflection-for-unknown-types/).

Answer (score 1):

From my comment on the OP:

> I'd avoid extended use of reflections if you are concerned about performance. If you can come up with an interface for the class(es) you are using, then I'd create one. Then write a wrapper that implements the interface by calling into the SharpBreak code, and stuff it in a separate DLL. Then dynamically load just your wrapper assembly and concrete wrapper type(s), and call into that interface. Then you don't have to do reflections at a method level.

I'm not sure all the classes you'd need, but here's a simple example of how you can hook into that library with loose coupling based on interfaces.

*In your program's assembly:*

```
public IExtensions
{
    void SendToAirbrake(Exception exception);
}

public static AirbreakExtensions
{
    private static IExtensions _impl;

    static()
    {
        impl = new NullExtensions();
        // Todo: Load if available here
    }

    public static void SendToAirbrake(this Exception exception)
    {
        _impl.SendToAirbrake(exception);
    }
}

internal class NullExtensions : IExtensions // no-op fake
{
    void SendToAirbrake(Exception exception)
    {
    }
}
```

*In a load-if-available (via reflections) assembly*

```
public ExtensionsAdapter : IExtensions
{
    void SendToAirbrake(Exception exception)
    {
        SharpBrake.Extensions.SendToAirbrake(exception);
    }
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that you only use reflections once (on load), and never touch it again.  It is also simple to modify to use dependency injection, or mock objects (for testing).

**Edit:**

For other types it will take a bit more work.

You might need to [use the Abstract Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) to instantiate an `AirbrakeNoticeBuilder`, since you need to deal directly with the interface, and can't put constructors in interfaces.

```
public interface IAirbrakeNoticeBuilderFactory
{
    IAirbrakeNoticeBuilder Create();
    IAirbrakeNoticeBuilder Create(AirbrakeConfiguration configuration);
}
```

If you're dealing with custom Airbreak structures, you'll have even more work.

E.g. for the `AirbrakeNoticeBuilder` you will have to create duplicate POCO types for any related classes that you use.

```
public interface IAirbrakeNoticeBuilder
{
    AirbrakeNotice Notice(Exception exception);
}
```

Since you're returning `AirbrakeNotice`, you might have to pull in nearly every POCO under the Serialization folder, depending on how much you use, and how much you pass back to the framework.

If you decide to copy the POCO code, including the whole object tree, you could [look into using AutoMapper to convert to and from your POCO copies](http://automapper.org/).

Alternately, if you don't use the values in the classes you're getting back, and just pass them back to the SharpBreak code, you could come up with some sort of opaque reference scheme that will use a dictionary of your opaque reference type to the actual POCO type.  Then you don't have to copy the whole POCO object tree into your code, and you don't need to take as much runtime overhead to map the object trees back and forth:

```
public class AirbrakeNotice
{
    // Note there is no implementation
}

internal class AirbreakNoticeMap
{
    static AirbreakNoticeMap()
    {
        Map = new Dictionary<AirbreakNotice, SharpBreak.AirbreakNotice>();
    }

    public static Dictionary<AirbreakNotice, SharpBreak.AirbreakNotice> Map { get; }
}

public interface IAirbrakeClient
{
    void Send(AirbrakeNotice notice);
    // ...
}

internal class AirbrakeClientWrapper : IAirbrakeClient
{
    private AirbrakeClient _airbrakeClient;

    public void Send(AirbrakeNotice notice)
    {
        SharpBreak.AirbrakeNotice actualNotice = AirbreakNoticeMap.Map[notice];
        _airbrakeClient.Send(actualNotice);
    }

    // ...
}

internal class AirbrakeNoticeBuilderWrapper : IAirbrakeNoticeBuilder
{
    AirbrakeNoticeBuilder _airbrakeNoticeBuilder;

    public AirbrakeNotice Notice(Exception exception)
    {
        SharpBreak.AirbrakeNotice actualNotice =
            _airbrakeNoticeBuilder.Notice(exception);

        AirbrakeNotice result = new AirbrakeNotice();
        AirbreakNoticeMap.Map[result] = actualNotice;

        return result;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Keep in mind that you only need to wrap the classes and parts of the public interface that you're going to use.  The object will still behave the same internally, even if you don't wrap its entire public interface.  This might mean you have to do less work, so think hard and try to wrap only what you need now, and what you know you're going to need in the future.  Keep [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it) in mind.

Comment: This particular example is a bit weird since you're wrapping a static class with a non-static class.  It works, tho.  If you have other classes you want to wrap (especially instanced classes), give me an example and I'll give you another code sample for it.

Comment: So you want to add an assembly in-between my app and SharpBrake.dll that has an explicit dependency on SharpBrake, and that is lazy loaded (instead of SharpBrake.dll)? Not a terrible idea, actually. Might even use IoC to do the registration instead of just having the .dll in the bin folder.

Comment: @asbjornu: Yes, exactly.  And big yes to IoC instead of the explicit reflections loading :)

Answer (score 0):

The programming style I have come to really like for problems like this is to write as much strongly-typed code as possible, and then hand off the logic from the dynamically-typed code to the strongly-typed code. So I would write your code like this:

```
  //your code which gets types
  Type clientType = exportedTypes.FirstOrDefault(type => type.Name == "AirbrakeClient");
  Type noticeType = exportedTypes.FirstOrDefault(type => type.Name == "AirbrakeNotice");

  //construct my helper object
  var makeDelegateHelperType=typeof(MakeDelegateHelper<,>).MakeGenericType(clientType, noticeType);
  var makeDelegateHelper=(MakeDelegateHelper)Activator.CreateInstance(makeDelegateHelperType);

  //now I am in strongly-typed world again
  var sendAction=makeDelegateHelper.MakeSendAction();
```

And this is the definition of the helper object, which is able to get away with fewer reflectiony calls.

```
public abstract class MakeDelegateHelper {
  public abstract Action<object> MakeSendAction();
}

public class MakeDelegateHelper<TClient,TNotice> : MakeDelegateHelper where TClient : new() {
  public override Action<object> MakeSendAction() {
    var sendMethod = typeof(TClient).GetMethod("Send", new[] { typeof(TNotice) });

    var client=new TClient();
    var action=(Action<TNotice>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<TNotice>), client, sendMethod);
    return o => action((TNotice)o);
  }
}
```