# Track Action<T> lambdas as Action<object>

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

Similar questions asked in the past:

- [Convert Action<T> to Action<object>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444246/convert-actiont-to-actionobject)
- [Expose Action<T> as Action<object>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609629/expose-actiont-as-actionobject)
- [How to cast object to Action<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800075/how-to-cast-object-to-actiont)

All got to the solution of wrapping the `Action<T> myActionT` into an anonymous `new Action<object>(o => myActionT((T)o));`
My use-case is that the initial, typed lambda is a data subscription callback, wrapping it into an anonymous one means I lose the ability to unsubscribe using the original `Action<T>`

I narrowed it down to this boilerplate example:

```
    internal class Demo
    {
        public class Dispatcher
        {
            private List<Action<object>> callbacks = new List<Action<object>>();

            public void Subscribe<T>(Action<T> cbk)
            {
                callbacks.Add(cbk); // <- compile error, Action<T> is contravariant
            }
            
            public void Unsubscribe<T>(Action<T> cbck)
            {
                callbacks.Remove(cbck); // <- compile error
            }
        }

        private static void Handler(int v) {}
        private static void Handler(string v) {}

        public static void Main()
        {
            var dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
            dispatcher.Subscribe<int>(Handler);
            dispatcher.Subscribe<string>(Handler);

            dispatcher.Unsubscribe<int>(Handler);
        }
    }
```

Of course I could go for overloading `Subscribe` (since I realistically only need value types)
Is there a better/more elegant way to properly track generic `Action` callbacks ?

**Later edit**: adding more details about my use case:

- I wrap a data feed of key-value (strings) updates
- clients can subscribe for fields and can choose to receive the values converted from string to other types
  (I'm using `TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type).ConvertFromString(fieldValue)` to deal with conversion)

e.g.:

```
 Subscribe<decimal>("price", (decimal px) => { /* do smthg with price*/ })
 Subscribe<bool>("opened", (bool opened) => { ... })
 Subscribe<string>("code", (string code) => { ... })
```

I feel that I'm down the rabbit hole with my current approach (function pointers / Delegate, tracking Type of subscriptions)
but I didn't find a more straightforward way of achieving this (besides overloading `Subscribe` with the types I need, which might be the sensible KISS choice)

Comment: "since I realistically only need value types". `string` is not a value type.

Comment: Also what are you planing to do with the `callbacks` except for subscribing/unsubscribing. Also have you looked into  [`events`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/)?

Comment: I added some more details about how I'm using `callbacks`

Comment: @AlinMotogna - Have you considered using Microsoft's Rx for this?

Comment: Never heard of it until now, looks heavy for my simple use case but I'll definetely look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's super simple. Try this instead:

```
private List<Delegate> callbacks = new List<Delegate>();
```

The C# compiler lets you cast any `Action<T>` to `Delegate`. Your code compiles and runs fine with that change.

---

However, I'd suggest changing your `Subscribe` method signature to this:

```
IDisposable Subscribe<T>(Action<T> cbk)
```

Then you don't need an `Unsubscribe` method - which would require you keeping a reference to the `Action<T> cbk`. Instead you just call `.Dispose()` on the subscription.

Try this code instead:

```
internal class Demo
{
    public class Dispatcher
    {
        private List<Delegate> callbacks = new List<Delegate>();

        public IDisposable Subscribe<T>(Action<T> cbk)
        {
            callbacks.Add(cbk);
            return new AnonymousDisposable(() => callbacks.Remove(cbk));
        }
    }

    private static void Handler(int v) { }
    private static void Handler(string v) { }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
        var subscription = dispatcher.Subscribe<int>(Handler);
        dispatcher.Subscribe<string>(Handler);

        subscription.Dispose();
    }
}

public sealed class AnonymousDisposable : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Action _action;
    private int _disposed;

    public AnonymousDisposable(Action action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (Interlocked.Exchange(ref _disposed, 1) == 0)
        {
            _action();
        }
    }
}
```